# Sending POST with objective-C and fetching it with python using flask

Tags: python, objective-c, flask, request, http-post

Its my first time here in stack overflow so be nice :P. Here is my method that should send some information to my web server.

```
-(IBAction)updateEvent:(id)sender{

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    [[dict objectForKey:@"name"] addObject:_getNameLabel.text];

    static NSString *url = @"http://localhost:5000/hello";
    NSError *error;
    NSData *event = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                         error:&error];

    if (! event) {
        NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:event];
        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[event length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    }


    // [gameInfoObject postEventInfo:event];

}
```

And here is the code that "should" handle the post message. All i want to do is to get that information and write it to an existing file.

```
import pickle
from flask import Flask
import json

@app.route('/hello/' , methods=['POST'])
def test():

    with open("text.txt", "w") as text_file:  #to check that it even gets here but it does not write anything at all to the file
        text_file.write("It came here!!")

    data = request.data
    dataDict = json.loads(data)

    with open('gameFile.txt', 'wb') as handle:
        pickle.dump(dataDict, handle)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

So when i run it i get no errors but i get no result either. The file is still empty what am i missing here? I appreciate all the help i can get!

Comment: try `return json.dumps({'msg': 'success'})` at the end of `def test` method.

Comment: where would i see that message? @SyedHabibM

Comment: In your `objective-c` code response?!

Comment: No i get nothing. I edited my question, i put another row in python code to check if it even gets there but it seems like it does not...@SyedHabibM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URLs don't match.

You have defined the route in Flask as `/hello/`.

```
@app.route('/hello/' , methods=['POST'])
```

When you make the request from Objective-C, however, you send it to `/hello`.

```
static NSString *url = @"http://localhost:5000/hello";
```

When Flask receives the request it sends a response with a `301` status code telling the client the resource has moved to `/hello/`. The client doesn't follow the redirect.

Either update your route or update your request and you should be all set.

**Edit:**

You also don't send the request. The code you posted prepared the POST request, but you need to open a connection. I'm not really familiar with Objective-C, but it should be something along the lines of the following.

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request 
                                                            delegate:self];

[connection start];
```

Comment: but in the browser to get to that place i need to write "http://localhost:5000/hello" not just hello? @dirn

Comment: If you go to `localhost:5000/hello` in your browser it will redirect to `localhost:5000/hello/`.

Comment: Aha now i got it hehe. I just changed the string url to @"http://localhost:5000/hello/" but it still didn't work :/ :( @dirn

Comment: Does the Flask portion work by itself? `curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "{'key':'value'}" http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello/` (or whatever the content type set by Object-C would be)

Comment: Yes it works, i start the web server and then in my shell i write what you wrote here and it writes to the file. So I'm guessing that I'm not sending a proper way in objective c? @dirn

Comment: Ah, yes, it looks like you aren't actually sending the request. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Worked like a charm :D thanks, one last question. am i doing request setValue right?, should it be "Content-type: application/json" since I'm sending json? @dirn